# How show the Facebook look and feel on Facebook app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, user-interface

I'm trying to use the Facebook api, there's any way to use the same look and feel (user interface) that use Facebook for forms, friends list, etc?, i saw fan page's using the same look and feel of Facebook...any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same style for your app via app's stylesheet as the facebook uses. Same fonts, colors, etc. If your unsure what those are then just open up developer tools on your browser or view source and navigate to facebook's .css file.

Comment: mmm thanks Wabbble, i know that, but i was thinking maybe facebook dev have some tools...thanks